# Finding Scaladoc help, reduceLeft

Tags: scala, scaladoc

Say, i am looking to better understand what `reduceLeft` method does when applied on a `Array[String]`

The [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array) says:
[image]

Ok, i must ask again, what does this method do? And what's more important, if i can't rely on scaladoc to tell me that, where can i find out?

Comment: To avoid others wasting their time... there's no significant info in ArrayOps, IndexSeqOptimized, or TraversableOnce, either.  And this is one of the most fundamental collection operations!  This kind of reference-doc issue is one of the most infuriating things about Scala.

Comment: [Bug reported](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6930), now go vote for it, will you ?

Comment: Fixed : https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/1860

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah - that Scaladoc entry could probably be more helpful.

Another useful source of documentation is the [Scala Documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org) site, which has [this](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/trait-traversable.html) to say about reduceLeft:

> xs reduceLeft op
>
> Apply binary operation op between successive elements of non-empty collection xs, going left to right.

So what it does is reduce a collection to a single value by successively applying a binary operator. Some examples:

```
scala> Array(1, 2, 3, 4) reduceLeft (_ + _)
res2: Int = 10

scala> Array("foo", "bar", "baz") reduceLeft (_ + _)
res3: String = foobarbaz
```

Comment: what is as binary operation?